# How do I get all parameter binding information from a CallableStatement?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, callable-statement

I'm working with legacy code that uses some convoluted logic to bind IN and OUT parameters in a JDBC CallableStatement.  The code looks like it is binding the correct types for IN and OUT parameters, but when the CallableStatement is executed the Oracle stored procedure  throws this Exception:

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'STORED_PROC_ABC'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

The "`line 1, column7:`" isn't helpful.  It's not pointing to anything in the stored proc.

I've written a simple stand-alone test case that calls the stored proc. with the same parameters and binding types as the legacy code, and it succeeds.

What I need is a way to compare the two CallableStatement objects in the legacy code and my stand-alone test to see what is different.

Is there a way to get the relevant parameter binding information (values and types) from a CallableStatement?  If there is some third party library that will do this that would be great, otherwise I'll need a way to dig out the various bindings.

Thanks.

Comment: Re: the first 2 answers below - CallableStatement.getParameterMetaData() does not work with Oracle drivers.  It just gives "Unsupported feature" Exceptions.  This has been a long-standing problem http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=585880

Comment: Isn't it possible to enable 10046 trace in the session (with level 12 ) and see the SQL and the Bind variables ?

Comment: This is the first I've heard of 10046 trace.  It's enabled on a per session basis, and I'm not sure what that means.  Do I have to enable it in the same CallableStatement (i.e. by executing an "ALTER SESSION ..." statement before the call to the stored proc)?

Comment: Dean- 10046 is an event that you can set for a given session, level 4 will give you the bind variables used and 12 will give the binds and wait information.However, in this case, the call is not even executed, since it is failing at the parse stage. So this wont help. Sorry!

Comment: I tried the 10046 event with levels 8 and 12, but got no output, probably for the reason you mentioned.  That's worth knowing for other situations, however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use CallableStatement.getParameterMetaData() 
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ParameterMetaData.html

Comment: I'm going to accept this as the answer with the caveat that CallableStatement.getParameterMetaData() doesn't work with Oracle drivers.

Answer (score 0):

JDBC CallableStatement objects are designed to represent calls to stored procedures in the database server.

Use `java.sql Interface ParameterMetaData`.

> An object that can be used to get information about the types and
>   properties of the parameters in a PreparedStatement object.